# Android, GL, screen size in IMMERSIVE MODE

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-4.4-kitkat, android-gui

I am developing with Nexus 4 KitKat 4.4 and 
trying to add `IMMERSIVE MODE` to my game.
I need screen height to set `glViewport` correctly.

Previously I used

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public static int getScreenHeight() {
    if (Main.m_activity == null)
        return -1;
    Display display = Main.m_activity.getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay();
    int height = -1;

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
        //width = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
        height = display.getHeight(); // deprecated
    }else{
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        height = size.y;
    }
    return height;

}
```

It does not return the real height of screen in `IMMERSIVE MODE`.

So I started to use values from

```
private static class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
```

and it worked fine when app starts. If I press home button and return to home screen and then back to game `onSurfaceChanged` get called again but with old wrong values (non-immersive mode screen size, smaller, regular)

IMMERSIVE SCREEN size is 800x1280
REGULAR size is 800x1184

When I get regular size and set it in `glViewport` then I get black line in top of screen.

**PS** Also `IMMERSIVE MODE` is lost when I press volume buttons.

**PS2**

I have following method impl. It does not help to handle screen/window resize.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
```

Comment: @payeli, please refrain from needlessly "improving" tags.  We already have *two* tags for kitkat, we did not need a third.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good article but still not enough.
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Right now we get screen size with

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
```

and if height decreased then we enable immersive mode again with 1 second delay.
This works but hacky and I look for canonical solution myself.

I am afraid it is just buggy in KitKat.
I do not any famous title that implemented immersive mode. (except our app of course )))

Comment: I do not like such delayed calls in general.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Display.getRealSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) to return the screen bounds without system windows.

Comment: If I do that way then when I press volume button immersive mode is lost. Display.getRealSize will still give give the screen size.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html) to get a callback when immersive mode is disabled/enabled. Using this, you can figure out the actual height of the screen.

Comment: Does it work when the user change the device volume with hardware buttons and the dialog appears above the app? In my tests, if the first thing the user does after opening the immersive app is changing the volume with hardware buttons, the app visibility is not changed.