# LibGDX: black bar on top in immersive mode

Tags: libgdx, android-immersive

I need to use immersive mode in my project, so I put this in my AdroidLauncher.java:

```
config.useImmersiveMode = true;
```

But I still have a black bar on top of the screen (as on screenshots below). How can I make the app draw there too?

[screenshot1, navigation turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvmXA.jpg)

[screenshot2, navigation turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhyqo.jpg)

I run the app on API 30 (Android 11), libGDX version is 1.11.0.

Comment: maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555083/android-gl-screen-size-in-immersive-mode you might be getting wrong values.